# Why wakeup interrupt is not working for STM32L412 in baremetal programming?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, bare-metal

I was trying baremetal programming for STM32L412T6 controller. I got stuck at RTC wakeup interrupt. My code is jumping to while(1) loop without going to the interrupt handler, Below mentioning my code.

```
int main(void)
{

    //LedConfig();
    rtc_domain_access();
    rtc_init();

    initialize_rtc_wakeup();
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(RTC_WKUP_IRQn);

    /* Loop forever */
    for(;;)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
}

void rtc_domain_access(void)
{
    /* Enable Clock for Power interface.*/
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (1U<<28);

    /*Disable backup domain write protection*/
    PWR->CR1 |= (1U<<8);
    while((PWR->CR1 & (1U<<8))==0);

    /*Reset the Backup domain*/
    RCC->BDCR |= (1U<<16);
    RCC->BDCR &= ~(1U<<16);

    /*Enable LSE Clock source and wait until LSERDY bit to set*/
    RCC->BDCR |= (1U<<0);
    while ((RCC->BDCR & (1U<<1)) == 0);

    /*Select LSE as RTC Clock*/
    RCC->BDCR |= (1U<<8);
    RCC->BDCR &= ~(1U<<9);

    /*Enable RTC Clock*/
    RCC->BDCR |= (1U<<15);

    /*Disable access to RTC registers*/
    RCC->APB1ENR1 &= ~(1U<<28);

}

void rtc_init(void)
{
     /* Disable the write protection for RTC registers */
    RTC->WPR = 0xCA;
    RTC->WPR = 0x53;

    /* Check if the Initialization mode is set */
    if((RTC->ICSR & (1U<<6))==0)
    {
        /* Set the Initialization mode */
        RTC->ICSR |= (1U<<7);

        /* Wait till RTC is in INIT state*/
        while((RTC->ICSR & (1U<<6))==0);
    }

     /* Clear RTC_CR FMT, OSEL, POL and TAMPOE Bits */
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<6);         //FMT
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<20);        //POL
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<21);        //OSEL
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<22);        //OSEL
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<26);        //TAMPOE

    /* Set RTC_CR register */
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<6);         //FMT bit set as Zero,Hour Format Selected as 24
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<20);        //POL bit set as Zero, Output polarity selected as high.
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<21);        //OSEL[22:21] set as zero, output selection disabled.
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<22);

    /* Configure the RTC PRER */
    RTC->PRER = 0xFF;           // Synchronus value set as 255
    RTC->PRER |= (0x7F<<16);    // Asynchronus value set as 127.

    /* Exit Initialization mode */
    RTC->ICSR &= ~(1U<<7);      // Clear INIT bit.

     /* If CR_BYPSHAD bit = 0, wait for synchro */
    if((RTC->CR & (1U<<5))==0)
    {
        /* Clear RSF flag */
        RTC->ICSR &= ~(1U<<5);

        /* Wait the registers to be synchronised */
        while((RTC->ICSR & (1U<<5))==0);
    }

    /* Clear RTC_CR TAMPALRM_PU, TAMPALRM_TYPE and OUT2EN Bits */
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<29);
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<30);
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<31);

    /*Set Output type as open drain pullup*/
    RTC->CR |= (1U<<30);

    /* Enable the write protection for RTC registers */
    RTC->WPR = 0xFF;

}


void Pwr_Clear_Flag(void)
{
    PWR->SCR = 0x1F;
}

void RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(void)
{
    /*Disable Write protection for RTC Registers*/
    RTC->WPR = 0xCA;
    RTC->WPR = 0x53;

    /*Disable the Wakeup Timer*/
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<10);

    /*In case of interrupt mode is used, the interrupt source must disabled*/
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<14);

    /* Wait till RTC WUTWF flag is set */
    while ((RTC->ICSR & (1U<<2)) == 0);

    /* Enable the write protection for RTC registers */
    RTC->WPR = 0xFF;
}

void RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(uint32_t RTC_WAKEUP_TIME_IN_SECONDS,uint32_t WakeUpAutoClr)
{
     /* Disable the write protection for RTC registers */
    RTC->WPR = 0xCA;
    RTC->WPR = 0x53;

     /* Clear WUTE in RTC_CR to disable the wakeup timer */
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<10);

     /* Clear flag Wake-Up */
    RTC->SCR = (1U<<2);

     /* Poll WUTWF until it is set in RTC_ICSR to make sure the access to wakeup autoreload
         counter and to WUCKSEL[2:0] bits is allowed. */
    if((RTC->ICSR & (1U<<6))==0)
    {
        while((RTC->ICSR & (1U<<2))==0);
    }


    /* Configure the Wakeup Timer counter and auto clear value */
    RTC->WUTR |= (RTC_WAKEUP_TIME_IN_SECONDS-1);
    RTC->WUTR |= (WakeUpAutoClr<<16);

   /* Configure the clock source */
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<0);
    RTC->CR &= ~(1U<<1);
    RTC->CR |= (1U<<2);

     /* RTC WakeUpTimer EXTI Configuration: Interrupt configuration */
    EXTI->IMR1 |= (1U<<20);
    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1U<<20);

     /* Configure the Interrupt in the RTC_CR register */
    RTC->CR |= (1U<<14);

     /* Enable the Wakeup Timer */
    RTC->CR |= (1U<<10);

     /* Enable the write protection for RTC registers */
    RTC->WPR = 0xFF;
}

void initialize_rtc_wakeup(void)
{
    RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer();
    Pwr_Clear_Flag();
    RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(RTC_WAKEUP_TIME_IN_SECONDS,WakeUpAutoClr);
}

void RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler(void)
{
    EXTI->PR1 = (1U<<20);
    if((RTC->MISR & (1U<<2))!=0)
    {
        //GPIOB->ODR |= 1<<13;
        RTC->SCR |= (1U<<2);
        count++ ;

    }

}
```

I tried to make a RTC wakeup interrupt in every 3 seconds, when it occurs I tried to increase the value of variable count, instead of that it goes to the infinite loop and changes the flag value.

Comment: There is no `while(1)` loop in your code, did you mean for-loop in the main function? If so, why it should not jump to the loop? Your code should stay in the for-loop, with periodic interrupts. And since you use magic numbers, I guess, no one would check whether register operations are correct.

Comment: sorry for mentioning as while(1), I was mentioning the infinite loop, but in my case the interrupt is not firing. its not going to the interrupt handler at all and stays at the for loop

Comment: Does _any_ interrupt work or just not this one? What's setting the global interrupt mask? `CPSIE i`.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry I didn't get your question. I am currently trying RTC wakeup interrupt. Previously I was able to try usart  and timer interrupts successfully.

Comment: Regular interrupts in any MCU are maskable, meaning there's a global mask bit that can be used to enable/disable all interrupts on the MCU. If you could use other interrupts, then we can rule that part out.

Comment: EXTI->IMR1 |= (1U<<20); I don't like this line. EXTI->IMR register, according to reference manual RM0402, page 239, has bits 19 and 20 reserved and "must be kept at reset value". And you actively set that bit. Something's fishy there.

Comment: @Ilya I am using STM32L412 not STM32F412, So I am looking into RM0394 refference manual. In STM32L412 RTC wakeup interrupt is set on the 20th interrupt line.

Comment: You're correct, sorry. Have a debug idea tho. Software-trigger EXTI_SWIER1 and see if you enter interrupt. If no, then it's probably NVIC configuration. Can you stop execution half-way and check that registers are set correctly? Also, just random idea, try providing clock to SYSCFG. It usually sets port mapping for EXTI, so maybe they must both be on.

Comment: You could consider enabling interrupt directly via registers: NVIC->ISER[IRQn >> 5] = (1 << (IRQn % 32)); (some index math magic).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved, what happened is RTC_WUTR register has reset value 0x0000FFFF before giving my wakeup clock I had to set the register to zero, once I done that my issue is Solved.